# Auto-translation of newline character in the terminal

Tags: c, terminal, ascii, posix, newline

I'm following along [here](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html).

I notice (this is not complete, just for demonstration) that at this point:

```
#include <termios.h>

  raw.c_iflag &= ~(ICRNL | IXON);
  raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
  raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
```

makes it so something like:

```
printf("\n");
```

simply advances to the next line without moving the cursor to the beginning. The text explains that typically `\n` gets translated to `\r\n` and `OPOST` disables this.

Relatedly, the `ICNRL` flag makes it so carraige returns (via `^M`) are correctly received by the terminal.

The manual is unenlightening:

> OPOST  Enable implementation-defined output processing.

Can someone explain the history, and what is going on here, in more detail?

How is it that `\n` is a single-byte then when doing a hexdump on files? Is the "auto-translation" to `\r\n` something that is done purely on a view-basis, and not actually for the bytes in text?

Comment: The auto translation is done only for terminals, not files. `termios` is for terminal control, that's what "term" in the name is short for.

Comment: [linux.se] or [retrocomputing.se] would be better places to ask about history of Unix features.

Comment: Note that C stdio functions do provide bidirectional line-termination translation behavior for text streams, including those connected to regular files, but this is independent of termios (which is not a C feature *per se*, but rather a Unix feature).

Comment: Could you elaorate @JohnBollinger

Comment: What elaboration is needed?

Comment: What do you mean by bi-directional line-termination translation behavior for text streams.

Comment: @user129393192 bi-directional line-termination translation is done for systems that use a different line-ending convention than a single ASCII LF for text files. For example Windows uses ASCII CR+LF line-endings in text files, so output text streams convert newline to CR+LF and input text streams convert CR+LF to newline. Unix systems use ASCII LF line-endings in text files, so no conversion is needed because newline is the same character code (10) as ASCII LF.

Comment: I see. And what I've learned here is that LF (or newline) is actually translated to CR + LF by the terminal when it is displaying info, whereas Windows already has it that way? @IanAbbott Seems confusing to have LF and Newline be the same thing.

Comment: In C, the `\a` (alert), `\b` (backspace), `\f` (form feed), `\n` (new line), `\r` (carriage return), `\t` (horizontal tab), and `\v` (vertical tab) character escape sequences correspond to characters with implementation-defined values. Typically, they map to ASCII control characters. There is no character called "new line" in ASCII so the ASCII LF (line feed) character is used instead.

Comment: In Windows, the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` streams are in text mode by default, but the `_setmode` function can be used with the `_fileno` function to change them to binary mode, e.g. `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);`, `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);`. Then you can check how the untranslated characters are handled by the console. The behavior of the Windows console can be changed with the `SetConsoleMode` function.

Comment: @IanAbbott but isn't it more than just C? For example, files use `\n` or the ASCII control character `LF` to mark end of line, which really means "the beginning of the next line", corresponding to `CR` + `LF`.

Comment: It really depends on the system. Classic Mac OS (before OSX) systems use ASCII `CR` (character 13) as the end of line sequence for text files, but the C `\n` character escape sequence still corresponds to ASCII `LF` (character 10) on those systems. Some systems with record-oriented file systems do not use any special character sequence at the end of a line, but each line becomes a "record" in the file. C text streaming has more work to do on those types of systems!

Comment: I think I'm sort of understanding. However, to be clear, what I observed here with `-opost` is that the true meaning of a "newline" as we want it to be displayed, is in fact a `CR` + `LF`, right? @IanAbbott

Comment: It would be appropriate to call CR+LF a "newline" sequence for a terminal. This really goes back to the days of teletypes and VDUs. On a teletype, CR (carriage return) tells the teletype to return the print carriage to the beginning of the line, and LF (line feed) tells the teletype to push the paper roller up one line. (Those actions are emulated on a VDU by moving the cursor to the beginning of the line for CR, and by moving the cursor down (possibly scrolling text up to make room) for LF.

Comment: Because Unix terminal driver code supported termios settings, there was no need for text files on Unix to contain CR+LF. Rather, the terminal driver could just be instructed by the termios settings to output a CR before each LF that was written to the terminal. And there were some advantages to having the end of a line of text represented by one character rather than a pair of characters.

Comment: I see, and since by default `OPOST` is on, this is that instruction, and taking it away requires you to emit the `\r` yourself. I imagine that emitting multiple `\r` is an idempotent operation.